# How to properly implement method affecting private parts of different classes

Tags: oop, private, encapsulation

Whenever I face a situation when *atomic* method should access private parts of different classes, the IMHO-fundamental impossibility of OOP to correctly implement such thing frustrates me.

Consider a simple example: some kind of collection should track its members, and members should track their owner (for example, relationship between creatures and locations in  game). I don't see perfect way to implement addition, removal, and transition of member to/from collection that would be OOP-secure. The 'lesser evil' I tend to use is have **doAction**-methods and **notify**-methods. So the member-collection example would look like this (in Java):

```java
class Member{
  private Collection owner;
  // notification methods
  public void notifyMoved(Collection to){
    owner = to;
  }
  // action methods
  public void moveTo(Collection to){
    owner.notifyRemoved(this);
    to.notifyAdded(this);
    owner = to;
  }
}

class Collection{
  private List<Member> members;
  // notification methods
  public void notifyAdded(Member item){
    members.add(item);
  }
  public void notifyRemoved(Memer item){
    members.remove(item);
  }
  // action methods
  public void add(Member item){
    item.notifyMoved(this);
    members.add(item);
  }
}
```

The problem is that there is possibility to break consistency by calling notification methods directly. 
Is there a better way to implement such things? C++ has friends, but what about Java and OOP in general?

**Edit**. In Java I can place them in one package, but I don't want to do this just to enable access to some methods. My question is more general and theoretical - where should actions (methods) be placed if they don't relate to one specific object class; and what to do if such actions need access to their privates.

### Summary of solutions

1. **Notification methods**. Notifier changes internal state of object according to *declared* change of environment. Calling notifires manually is a threat to consistency.
2. **Language-specific accessors**.

   - **Java**: Package-private access.
   - **Java**: Nested classes. (e.g. Collection being outer and Member being inner).
   - **C++**: Friend classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shortcoming of java, because it lacks the "friends" concept. You could put them in the same package and use "package" access modifier for the methods (package = no access modifier).